# Unable to install cv2 in Python 3.5 on Ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-18.04, opencv, python

I have created a virtual environment on Ubuntu 18.0 series with Python 3.5. I am unable to import cv2, error is no module found and a trace back related to Python 2.7. I have already pip installed opencv-Python and opencv-contrib-Python but still the issue persists.
Please help at the earliest.

Comment: Maybe because you should use `pip3`, `python3`. Can you try again with these?

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried that as well.

Answer (score 2):

There a few ways you could go about this:

- #### Using python3

Try:

```sh
python3 -m pip install opencv-python opencv-contrib-python
```

- #### Deactivate your virtual enviroment

Try deactivating your virtual environment by typing `deactivate` and re-activating it again.

And If all else fails:

- #### Reinstalling Python

Python 3.5 and below no longer has official support, so that may (most likely not) be the problem.

My Tutorial for re-installing python can be found [here](https://dev.to/codejym/how-to-install-python-on-debian-4o8o).

After that, try:

```sh
pip install opencv-python opencv-contrib-python
```

Comment: Really, thankful tried all the approaches you suggested but still the same import error is persisting. I have updated my python version to 3.7.9 as well.When I do pip list there is a library with a name cv-bridge but no cv2.

Comment: It’s working now, the issue was in the Python path in bashrc file. I just used unset PYTHONPATH and then imported in Python 3.

Comment: I see. Sorry That I could not be of much help. Good to hear that you solved the problem though :)

Comment: Thank you! I tried a bunch of solutions and this is the first one I found that worked.